# Scala - an unsuspicious implicit method is messing up the entire CanBuildFrom thing

Tags: scala, types, implicit

I have the follwoing code:

```
trait DBO
trait BSONWriter[S]

trait HasWriter {
   implicit def writer[T <: BSONWriter[_ <: DBO]]: T
}
```

And everything was fine! Except for when I mix it into my `objects`, the `map` methods of all the collections and other stuff that implicitly uses `CanBuildFrom` in all these objects and their companion classes now show errors with messages like:

> - ambiguous implicit values: both method writer in trait Saving of type [T <: reactivemongo.bson.handlers.BSONWriter[_ <: traits.DBO]]=>
>     T and method canBuildFrom in object Buffer of type [A]=>
>     scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer.Coll,A,scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[A]]
>     match expected type 
>     scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[models.world.Star],traits.IsInWorld
>     with org.bundlelib.traits.Groupable{def asBSON: 
>     reactivemongo.bson.AppendableBSONDocument},That]

Now I do not understand, why is that? The signatures of the confused implicit methods are different! And how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a short example will show the problem:

```
trait Foo

trait Implicits {
    implicit def b[T <: String]: T

    implicit def run = implicitly[Foo]
}
```

This compiles correctly -- so what's going on? Run with `-Xprint:typer`:

```
implicit def run: foo.Foo = scala.this.Predef.implicitly[foo.Foo](Implicits.this.b[Nothing])
```

The problem is that `Nothing` (and other types, as far as the compiler knows), are both `Foo` and `<: String`. The type of `b` is much too polymorphic, so it matches basically *any* implicit you are after. This is what is happening in your example: `Nothing` is both `T <: BSONWriter[_ <: DBO]` and `CanBuildFrom[...]`.

I suppose my suggestion to you would be don't make implicit methods that are so polymorphic. In your example, I'm actually wondering if you really want `writer` to be as polymorphic as it is. Is maybe this what you want?

```
trait HasWriter[T <: BSONWriter[_ <: DBO]] {
   implicit def writer: T
}
```

that would avoid the implicit problem.